# How to fix non-identical quotation marks in tumblr

Tags: tumblr, quotation-marks

Problem here:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fmUS.png]

Here the HTML:

```
<a rel="bookmark" href="http://blog.expectlabs.com/post/56248790540/why-we-say-ah-choo">Why We Say “Ah-choo"</a>
```

Here I can see that the marks around `“Ah-choo"` are different. But I typed them from my keyboard in the Tumblr interface as `""`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you edit the content and replavce the quotation mark? Can you reproduce the same problem with another post?

Comment: The exact thing happens in every post, even if I try to replace the quotation mark.